# Aurelia minimal project for work inside Browser (no http server)

Tags: html, css, ecmascript-6, aurelia, ecmascript-2016

How to set a Aurelia minimal project for work inside Browser
(no http server) how to set a bare minimum aurelia system/boilerplate
to work just inside browser (no NodeJS)
mainly for understanding/learning purpouses

---

- no NodeJS (using just Javascript from latest browsers, advise Firefox Developper)
- no npm (just download latest version and copy minimum files)
- no folders (all in root flat folder for clarification and learn purpouses)
- just ES6/7 (no Typescript, no Babel, etc)
- just CSS use (no SASS, no LESS, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

You should read the [Quick Start](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/quick-start/1) in the docs and download the [Basic Project](http://aurelia.io/downloads/basic-aurelia-project.zip) Setup

However, there's no way to use ES6/7 without Babel (or other js compiler) today.

Comment: without using Babel what ES version can I use ?ES5 ?ES6

Comment: You can use ES5. But trust me, if you want to use a mordern js framework, go with ES6/7 or Typescript. The basic project I've mentioned is configured to use babel transpiler on-the-fly, so you don't have to worry about any tooling or configuration. That's gonna be transparent for you ;)

Comment: Obrigado Fabio... se tiveres mais informação sobre isto que queiras acrescentar agradeço... abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this github repo: [aurelia/aurelia](https://github.com/aurelia/aurelia) which has a simple starter kit with a concatenated script-tag ready build.